# Python re.match returns none. How to modify the search string?

Tags: python, regex, line

Below are my lines:

```
num1    -num2 num3: var.shift varstate=shift, var3=num, var4=False/True,  Shift   0xabc5d 

num1    -num2 num3: var.shift varstate=shift, var3=num, var4=False/True,  Shift 0xabc08 

num1    -num2 num3: var.shift varstate=shift, var3=num, var4=False/True,  Shift [38b]0xabc34
```

I am trying to get the hexvalue from the lines. I need the hexvalue in only one of the line which is in the form of [38b]0xabc1234567890000000000000000000000000. I dont need all the hex values.

All my hex values int he line start with 0x so I have given that in re.match

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re
import binascii
import string
value_file = open("test2.txt","r")
file2 = open("out.txt", "w")

for line in value_file:
    line_string = str(line)
    line_nospace = line.replace(" ", "")
    lines_cont = line_nospace.rstrip("\n")
    reg_match = re.match(r'\[([38b]]*)\](0-9a-zA-Z)', lines_cont)
    print reg_match
```

Comment: If you have a `0xdeadd00d` in your text, please write `0xdeadd00d`, don't write `hexvalue`. It makes the question that much harder to answer, not seeing the data you're seeing.

Comment: Which line do you need a hexvalue from? The first, second, or third?

Comment: I need the hexvalue which is 38 bits long and it is present in one of the lines.

Comment: So one of the lines has 0xabcde99999999999999999999999999999999. Just an example.

Comment: I removed the white space in the lines. So now I have the lines as continuous. I am not sure how to do a re.search for the hexvalue which starts with 0xabc and is 38 bit long.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression `(.*) 0x(\.*)` escapes the period in the second group, which means that it is matching zero or more periods rather than zero or more arbitrary characters.

If you want to match everything after the `0x`, remove the back slash.

Comment: Okay so instead of matching a string may be I should search for the hex value with is 38bits long??? Because this did not work and I am thinking I did not explain it earlier that I am trying to get the hexvalue which is 38 bits long in one of the lines. so may be re.search?

Comment: What will be the regular expression to search for in a  line like below: `fooabc[foo]shiftarg[38b]0xabc123456789`. I need the hex value 0xabc123456789 which is followed by [38b] in each line.

Comment: If you want to match a hex string, you could use an expression like `0x([0-9A-Fa-f]+)`.  If you want to match a hex string of a particular length, you could use something like `0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{10})` (for exactly 10 hex digits) or `0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,10})` (for 1 to 10 hex digits).  What you put in the rest of the expression will depend on what you're trying to match exactly.